# How do I find an integral of the form $\int$ cos(nx)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I came across this problem

$$I_n = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {\cos(nx)}{1-\cos(x)}dx$$

I've seen methods to solve integrals of the form $\int\cos^n(x)$ etc., but not of this form. What is the basic transformation to be done to start solving it?

Comment: This integral doesn't exist

Comment: This integral diverges as mentioned in the Caveat to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1712554).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove this integral problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1712524)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the definite integral $$I_n = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {\cos(nx)}{1-\cos(x)}dx$$ there is major issue at the bounds.

To show it, consider Taylor series around $x=0$ $$\frac {\cos(nx)}{1-\cos(x)}=\frac{2}{x^2}+\left(\frac{1}{6}-n^2\right)+\frac{1}{120} \left(10 n^4-10 n^2+1\right)
   x^2+O\left(x^4\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

To integrate $cos(nx)$, you can use Euler's formula ($e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x))$.

$\cos(nx) = \Re(e^{inx})$, so $\int \cos(nx) = \Re(\int e^{inx})$, where $\Re(z)$ denotes the real part of the complex number $z$. We can treat i like an ordinary constant.

With the quotient, it becomes a different problem. You can see the indefinite integral [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20cos(nx)%2F(1-cos(x))).